# what is the best method to capture video from webcam using C#.NET?

Tags: .net-4.0, webcam, video-capture

I need to capture video from the webcam and save to file(mp4 format). what is best way to do this using C#.net 4.0 application?

Are there any solutions which doesn't involve WIA(Windows Image Acquisition) / DirectShow? Or do i need to use either one of them?

Comment: Define "best" (performance? coding speed? file size? something else?) and please explain why you want to exclude WIA and DirectShow.

Comment: yes best in performance and also which doesn't require me to capture frame by frame and create video out of it.
and its not that i want to exclude WIA and DirectShow but some other solution which gives me higher level control instead of win32 APIs

Comment: WIA gets you stills, DirectShow gets you streaming video. DirectShow is primary API and with highest level of control. Anything else will get you lower level of control, still might be a good wrapper over DirectShow. Media Foundation and VFW are other video capture APIs in Windows. The latter is deprecated and they both are inferior in capabilities.

Comment: Any examples on how to use microsoft media foundation with webcam to capture videos?

Comment: Media Foundation SDK Samples - Video Capture http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#video_capture

Answer (score 5):

I know a third party toolkit named [leadtools](https://www.leadtools.com/) that might help you. This toolkit uses the DirectShow's filters and codecs to capture videos from webcams. Also, it provides easy ways manipulate the captured videos and save them with many formats including the MP4.  For more information, you can check this [Tutorial](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/multimedia/to/leadtools.topics.multimedia~leadtools.topics.multimedia.creatingamultimediacaptureapplication.html)

Comment: Looks like that is what i needed... Anyways, i'll try and let you know... Thanks...